# Is it on-topic to provide individual answers to interview questions?

Tags: discussion

When I read this: [Need help on this Interview question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20136/need-help-on-this-interview-question) I wondered if it should be considered on topic or not?

If this question is acceptable, I'd expect a huge flood of "How to answer this interview question?" questions.

It doesn't matter to me either way, but in other non-stackexchange forums, I've seen this flavor of question become overwhelming. I could easily imagine a new stackechange community devoted entirely to asking and answering interview questions.

There is a precedent to be set here.

Comment: similar discussion at Prog meta: [Why do interview questions make poor Programmers.SE questions?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6360/why-do-interview-questions-make-poor-programmers-se-questions)

Comment: Some [previous discussion](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1959/2322)

Comment: Hi Joe, please take a look through the linked dup as I suspect you'll find the answer there, with the short answer being "Don't answer the interview questions directly; instead, explain *how* to approach the interview questions".  If you feel there's still some doubts in your mind or something isn't covered, I suggest editing this to clarify and then flag and I'll reopen. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. My prediction is that we'll see more and more "How do I answer this interview question" category questions with thousands of different questions in the body. The answers will vary from repetitions of "how to approach interview questions" responses, to repetitions of "here is how I answered during my interview" responses. Ok by me. (My preference would be to have a separate stackexchange site for Interview Questions)